# Where do I find the packages downloaded by Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, package

I have poor internet at home and hence I am not able to download the packages which are downloaded by Android SDK like Android 4.2 package etc. I just wanted to know that is it possible to find these packages if yes where do i find them and if I copy them from my friends PC to my PC will it affect anything ?

Comment: get it online where you have a fast data connection: the root repo is: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/ and the mirror is: http://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/android/repository/

Comment: @pskink you mean to say i can download from mirror and then place in sdk folder and it will work fine ?

Comment: you can download from the repo (faster)  or from the mirror (slower)

Comment: @pskink its showing Error page not found for repo

Comment: because you cannot browse the repo,  but direct read acces is possible,  just see the mirror fullpath and replace it with the repo prefix, like this: mirror http://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, repo https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml

Comment: @pskink did not get you can you please give the link of repo

Comment: what didn't you get? you have two links above, just compare them

Answer (score 1):

In my PC, they are located at the following directory: C:\Users\MY_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

And I think you can copy them from your friend without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy it from your friend's pc, by going to the android sdk folder and then coping all platforms you need and paste them to your pc in the platforms it will work :-)